# Как лучше сделать модальное окно на js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот хочу создать например 3 модальных окон на каждые кнопки, и не знаю как правильнее, в html создать разметку модального окна, и скрывать по display:none/block . Или все таки лучше написать разметку в переменную , и добавлять и удалять через js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас модальное окно будет всегда для одной задачи с одинаковыми данными, то можно просто показывать/скрывать. Если у модального окна разные задачи, то лучше делать вставку окна в документ по запросу. При простых шаблонах, где только серединка меняется, например сообщение одно, это не проблема и можно как угодно. А если у окна меняется много чего (заголовок, размер, кнопки внизу, ...), то пришлось бы делать какие-то сильно-умные очистки сначала.

В вашем случае если для каждой кнопки всегда своё окно с одинаковыми данными внутри, то можно просто создать сразу три окна в HTML и показывать/скрывать каждое из них.

Или можно сделать универсальное окно, у которого один шаблон, но разные данные для каждой из кнопок. Это может уменьшить количество копипасты если у окна много элементов дизайна.

Comment: У меня в 3 модальных окон будет разная ширина и высота, и контент, то лучше будет просто готовые розметки поставить  в html и скрывать , открывать?

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo ширина и высота - это стили, они к разметке окон не относятся. Окнам можно просто класс поставить для разной ширины например. Если вы не видите особых преимуществ в том или ином подходе, то просто сделайте как угодно. В небольших сайтах или простых приложениях разницы не будет. Притом это переделать легко весьма потом.

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу на примере открытия модального окна для изменения полей имени и описания.

Для начала, вам необходимо будет сверстать так скажем компонент этого самого окна, как он будет выглядеть, будет ли у него затемнен задний фон, и прочие детали.

Лично я, размещаю разметку таких окон в теге `<section>` сразу после тега `<body>`. Естественно классу задаю так называемый модификатор класса `modal-opened` (подробнее можете ознакомиться с методологией БЭМ), он пишется сразу после основного класса `<section class="modal modal-opened">`, ему ставится css-правило `visibility: visible;` и `opacity: 1;` (для удобного стилизования всплытия окон).

В скрипте соотвественно прописывается обработчик, по клику на который будет удаляться класс modal-opened или добавляться.

Это стандартный способ открытия и закрытия модальных окон, именно с помощью добавления и удаления доп. классов (они же модификаторы класса).

```
модальная_переменная.classList.remove('modal_opened');
```

Comment: А если добавлять modal Окно после в секции после кнопки ? или не важно где добавить розметку?

Comment: Модальное окно следует размещать в начале разметки, чтобы оно перекрыло все элементы снизу и не пришлось разбираться с z-index